# grunt-newer won't work properly with Watchify

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I use **Grunt** for **Node** with a bunch of packages. For example **jsHint**, **jsDoc**, **Browserify**, **Uglify** ...

I run the **Gruntfile** with **Watchify** and **Newer** for automation. So far, so good.

The Gruntfile, which works totaly fine:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        jshint: {
            all: ['my/js/files/*.js']
        },
        jsdoc : {
            dist : {
                src: ['my/js/files/*.js'], 
                options: {
                    destination: 'doc'
                }
            }
        },
        browserify: {
            'public/js/files/script.js': ['my/js/files/*.js']
        },
        uglify: {
            my_target: {
                files: {
                    'public/js/files/script.js': ['public/js/files/script.js']
                }
            }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'public/html/index.html': ['public/html/index.html']
                }
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            combine: {
                files: {
                    'public/css/css.min.css': ['my/css/files/*.css']
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            javascript: {
                files: ['my/js/files/*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'jsdoc', 'browserify', 'uglify']
            },
            html: {
                files: ['public/html/index.html'],
                tasks: ['htmlmin']
            },
            css: {
                files: ['public/css/*.css'],
                tasks: ['cssmin']
            }
        }
    });

    // load plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsdoc');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
};
```

It works as far as I only use **Newer** for **jsHint**. But if I try the same with **jsDoc** or **Uglify** I get Error-Messages.

**Example:**

I try this ...

```
tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'newer:jsdoc:all', 'browserify', 'uglify']
```

instead of ...

```
tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'jsdoc', 'browserify', 'uglify']
```

I get Error-Messages:

```
Running "newer:jsdoc:all" (newer) task
Warning: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Why does it work for jsHint but not for the rest? Has anybody an idea? Would much appreciate some Hints!

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the target of your jshint task is `all`, so `newer:jshint:all` is correct.

your jsdoc target is `dist`, so you have to use this target: `newer:jsdoc:dist`

for you it is even easier, you only have one target per task (only your watch task has multiple targets) so you could only do it like this:

```
 ['newer:jshint', 'newer:jsdoc', 'browserify', 'uglify']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. The good explanation is even more worth! :)